# How to set dcterms:modified when using ebooklib in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, properties, ebooklib

There was a problem while converting docx to epub in python3. When trying to set dcterms:modified as specified in the document, a second property is created and the first is always set to the current date and time.

**Code:**

```
        book.set_unique_metadata(
          None,
          "meta",
          info[key].strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),
          { "property":"dcterms:modified" }
        )
```

**Result:**

```
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    <meta property="dcterms:modified">2023-08-30T08:14:25Z</meta>
    <meta name="generator" content="Ebook-lib 0.18.1"/>
    <dc:identifier id="id">137c26de-29c8-45a7-966a-c710f35af3c3</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>1-58.docx</dc:title>
    <dc:creator id="creator">Author Document</dc:creator>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <meta property="dcterms:modified">2023-04-22T10:47:00Z</meta>
  </metadata>
```

Tell me, how can I correctly set the dcterms:modified to "2023-04-22T10:47:00Z" in epub as in a document, and not add a second property?

*Python 3.11
EbookLib 0.18*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.